# how to remove VLC from computer search and as default player

Tags: uninstall, vlc

I having problem with opening videos using vlc player so I removed it completely using many commands such as

1. `sudo apt-get remove vlc`
2. `sudo apt-get purge vlc`
3. `sudo apt-get remove vlc-data`
4. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
5. `sudo aptitude remove vlc`

Now `vlc` command shows vlc not installed even vlc not listed in  `dpkg --l` results.
**I tried all possible commands, rebooting computer but still vlc media player visible to me in computer search and recommended application for video**. I thought by installing new vlc will overcome problem of opening video but problem as it is.
How can overcome this issue? I'm using ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: May be its desktop file is not removed. `locate vlc | grep .desktop` to see if the file exists..

Comment: Is it installed as a snap by any chance? `sudo snap remove vlc`

Comment: yes I installed it using snap. I removed snap(which includes vlc data) folder from my user directory nothing happened. same snap folder is at / directory deleting this folder will harm my computer?

Comment: hey @ArchismanPanigrahi "sudo snap remove vlc"  worked thanks..

Comment: @yogesh.ve I am going to write it as an answer. If it worked, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned "installing new VLC", and since `dpkg` cannot trace it, you probably installed it as a `snap`.

`sudo snap remove vlc` should remove `vlc` installed with `snap`.